# How to exit composite field validation when Type constraint returns violation?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Let's say I want to validate email variable, which is submitted to the controller action:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type;

$constraints = new Collection([
    'fields' => [
        'email' =>  [
            new Type([
                 'type' => 'string',
                 'message' => static::ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID,
            ]),
            new NotBlank([
                'message' => static::ERROR_EMAIL_REQUIRED,
            ]),
            new Email([
                'message' => static::ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID,
            ]),
            new Length([
                'max'        => 128,
                'maxMessage' => static::ERROR_EMAIL_TOO_LONG,
            ]),
        ],
    ],
]);
```

If the user submits `email[]=1`, then `UnexpectedTypeException` will be thrown and I have to handle it manually, return a translated message, inject translator, etc.

Is there a way to tell the Symfony validator to validate the `Type` first and ignore the other constraints if the `Type` fails (only return the `Type` error)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid multiple error messages you could use the GroupSequence features as described here:

[How to Sequentially Apply Validation Groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html)

Hope this help

Comment: A bit too complicated for my use case, but definitely looks like the correct solution from Symfony (assuming there is no simpler one).